# Sort in laravel eager loading?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

In my laravel project I am loading all the posts, posts author, replies and replies author using eager loading feature.

```
$pin = Posts::with('author', 'replies', 'replies.author')->find($pin_id);
```

Here is Replies model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Replies extends Model
{
    public function replyable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id');
    }

}
```

Is it possible to sort the `replies` in descending order by its(replies) id while we fetch all the posts using the eager loading feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this should help.

```
Posts::with(['replies' => function($query) {
          $query->orderBy('id');
}])->find($pin_id);
```

Comment: Ow! Lots of thanks. Also, can you explain a bit if i wanted to paginate through all the comments? using the paginate() method?

Comment: Em...  I don't think that you can paginate here. When you eager loading your relation, you should have a clean instance of  a model. In  `with` method you can filter or sort or maybe load another relation...
 Hope it is clear :)